# limits of riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$ be a Riemann integrable function on the closed interval from $s$ to $t$. Let $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of Riemann sums for $g$ with the property that the fineness of the partition for each $M_n$, lets call it $\delta_n$, vanishes in the limit. I wish to check my work for the problem that if $Q$ is the Riemann integral for $g$, then $Q=\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n$.

The structure of the proof is the following. First, I show that $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Second, I acknowledge the fact that since $M_n\in\mathbb{R}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. Third, I show that $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $Q$ as desired.

To begin with, fix $\epsilon>0$. Then, by the definition of the Riemann sum, we know that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $\delta_n<\delta$ then $|M_n - Q| < \epsilon$. Since $\delta_n \to 0$ we know that we can find an integer $N$ such that if $m>N$ and $n>N$ then $\delta_n < \delta$ and $\delta_m < \delta$. Thus, $|M_n - Q| < \epsilon$ and $|M_m - Q| < \epsilon$. Hence, $|M_n - M_m| < 2\epsilon$. Hence $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

As acknowledged $\mathbb{R}$ is complete so the sequence converges. Once again we know that for any fixed $\epsilon>0$ that we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $\delta_n<\delta$, $|M_n - Q|<\epsilon$. Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n = Q$.

Could someone check this if it correct? If not, could they help me get started on the right track.

Comment: Which definition of Riemann integral do you use? The one I know is precisely what you want to prove, namely as the limit of Riemann sums, but you seem to use it (in the so-called $\epsilon-\delta$ form).

Comment: Ok, but that is not so different than what you are trying to prove. What you do is simply a transition from the $\epsilon-\delta$ to a sequential argument, no?

Comment: Well, if that's what you want to prove then there is no problem in your proof, except possibly some redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is this: (i) Using $M_n\to Q$, you show that $\{M_n\}_n$ is Cauchy, (ii) by the completeness of the real line $\{M_n\}_n$ is convergent, (iii) you show $M_n\to Q$.

But directly proving (iii) is sufficient: Since $\delta_n\downarrow0$, $\exists N,\forall n\geq N:\delta_n<\delta$. Hence by the definition of Riemann integral $|Q-M_n|<\epsilon$.